# Is there a way to install just Mosquitto Pub?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm working on a Linux system (a based of OpenWRT version) that has not much storage (<3MB) and no active internet connection, however I need to be able to publish to a MQTT-Broker some outputs. Is there a way for me to install just the publisher part of Mosquitto to save space or another way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Without a LOT more information about the system this question is basically impossible to answer. e.g. we have no idea about what OS is being used...

But for a system with such tightly constrained storage your best option will probably to build the components you need from scratch that way you have complete control over what gets installed.

You could build the mosquitto tools and then strip them before copying just the binary you want (and any require libraries) to the system.

If you install from pretty much any Linux package management system you are likely to get all the tools plus man pages which will inflate the install footprint.

EDIT -

But all that said, a quick look at the available packages for OpenWRT implies that the existing packages that include both the broker and the command line tools would use 129kb (99 + 30 and is less if you don't need SSL 85 + 28) when installed (this assumes the pre-requisites are already installed)

https://openwrt.org/packages/table/start?dataflt%5BDescription_wiki*%7E%5D=mosquitto

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have since edited the question. It's essentially a router that runs a linux based system that is based of OpenWRT (RutOS)

Comment: The second part of the answer still applies with that little storage.